# How to get XSLT key-function working with my scenario?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, biztalk

**Here is my in-data:**

```
<Results>
 <Result>
  <Id>1</Id>
 </Result>
 <Result>
  <Id>2</Id>
 </Result>
</Results>
<Results>
 <RefId>1</RefId> 
 <Text>One</Text>     
</Results>
<Results>
 <RefId>2</RefId>    
 <Text>Two</Text>  
</Results>
```

**How the output should be:**

```
<OBR></OBR>
<OBX>One</OBX>
<OBR></OBR>
<OBX>Two</OBX>
```

**My xslt-code**

```
 <xsl:key name="test" match="Results/Result" use="Id"/>  
 
 <xsl:template match="Results/Result">
 <OBR></OBR>

 <xsl:for-each select="Results[key('test', RefId)/RefId]">
 <OBX><xsl:value-of select="Text" /></OBX>
 </xsl:for-each>

 </xsl:template>
```

**It does not work. My result is:**

```
<OBR></OBR>
<OBX>One</OBX>
<OBX>Two</OBX>
<OBR></OBR>
<OBX>One</OBX>
<OBX>Two</OBX>
```

I assume that the problem is with the for-each in my template.. It´s looping twice every time the template runs. Any suggestions?

Comment: 1. Your input is not well-formed XML and cannot be processed by XSLT. 2. Please explain in words the logic you are trying to apply.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I have solved it and added the solution in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I complicated it unnecessarily much with they key-function. I solved with just creating a variable named ID and it´s based on the Id-field. Then in the for-each I just tested if the variable and the RefId-element matched and it works perfectly.

```
<xsl:template match="Results/Result">
<xsl:variable name="ID" select="Id"></xsl:variable>

<OBR></OBR>

<xsl:for-each select="Results[(RefId = $ID)]">

<OBX><xsl:value-of select="Text" /></OBX>

</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```